# Connect Redis not retaining data

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node.js-connect

I'm following an example in *Node.js in Action* and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Here's my code:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(connect);

var app = connect();
app.use(connect.favicon());
app.use(connect.cookieParser('Cereal killin keybored kittty'));
app.use(connect.session({
  store: new RedisStore({prefix: 'boom'})
}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  if (req.session.views) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views  + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + req.session.cookie.maxAge + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>httpOnly: ' + req.session.cookie.httpOnly + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>path: ' + req.session.cookie.path + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>domain: ' + req.session.cookie.domain + '</p>');
    res.write('<p>secure: ' + req.session.cookie.secure + '</p>');
    res.end();
    req.session.views += 1;
  } else {
    req.session.views += 1;
    res.end('Welcome to the session demo. Refresh the page.');
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

No matter how many times I refresh, req.session.views remains equal to 1. Any help would rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the session explicitly after changing it:

```
  ...
  req.session.views += 1;
} else {
  req.session.views += 1;
  res.end('Welcome to the session demo. Refresh the page.');
}
req.session.save();
...
```

I think the only store for which an explicit `save()` isn't required is the `MemoryStore` (just checked the example code for *Node.js in Action*, that also uses the `MemoryStore`).

Comment: this is not working for me, care to share... 3 years later what your config looked like? lol.

Comment: @Phil here's a standalone version that works for me: https://gist.github.com/5a0d9f5c576a5c2f2be579eaaa9554d3 (the counter may seem broken as it may increase by 2 for each reload, but that's because the browser is also requesting a non-existent `/favicon.ico` for which the counter is increased as well; I didn't bother filtering that out)